# Type with a guaranteed size of 2?

Tags: c++, types, c++14

The C++ standard doesn't require exact sizes of the integral types, which can sometimes lead to very unexpected results. Some smart people then introduced the `<cstdint>` header containing (optional) typedefs like `int64_t` for types with exactly 64-bit width. This is not what want.

Is there an (possibly optional) integral type with the property `sizeof(mysterious_type) == 2` for whatever system is defined on?

**Reasoning:** I'm trying to figure out the system's endianess. For this, after reviewing many questions on this board, I though I would just define an integral type with size 2, assign one to it and check endianess like this:

```
enum endianess { LITTLE_ENDIAN, BIG_ENDIAN };

typedef utwowitdhtype test_t; // some unsigned type with width 2

endianess inspectSystem() {
    static_assert(sizeof(twowitdhtype) == 2, "twowitdhtype is not size 2??!?!!");

    test_t integral = 0x1;
    return *reinterpret_cast<char*>(&integral) == 0 ? BIG_ENDIAN : LITTLE_ENDIAN;
}
```

While this is a reasoning why I would be interested in such a type, finding such a type is not to solve the problem but out of curiousity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on the machine that has a `char` size != 8 bits, *you will have bigger portability issues* you'll have to tackle - it's simpler to just do `static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8, "assuming 8-bit chars")` than do weird things in the name of false portability - if you can't test it, how can you say you did it right?

Although for finding endianess it won't help at all, you can get such type by using type traits.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Identity
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename... Args>
struct ShortTypeFinder;

template<>
struct ShortTypeFinder<>
{

};

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct ShortTypeFinder<Head, Tail...>
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<sizeof(Head) == 2, Identity<Head>, ShortTypeFinder<Tail...>>::type::type type;
};

typedef ShortTypeFinder<short, int, long, long long>::type integral_type_with_sizeof_two;

int main()
{
    integral_type_with_sizeof_two x = 0;
    static_assert(sizeof x == 2, "sizeof(x) must be 2");
    static_assert(std::is_same<integral_type_with_sizeof_two, short>::value, "it's short on my machine");
}
```

If such type doesn't exist, the `ShortTypeFinder<TYPES>::type` will fail to compile.

Comment: as sizeof(char)==1 by definition, putting `signed char` into that list is useless

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to define `type` in the general case. The general practice here is simply to not define it, or even leave the class incomplete, as these ones always result in a compilation error when the appropriate type is not found, while a `void` can be valid in some contexts (such as when taking a pointer of it).

Comment: @petersohn You're fully right, originally I wrote this answer as a proof-of-concept rather than an actual answer, but now that this has 7 upvotes, it needs to be updated. (and in fact, after the update `::type` is not defined if there's no such type - it's friendlier for SFINAE)

Comment: What's the purpose of `Identity` here?

Comment: @petersohn Lazy evaluation of both branches of `std::conditional` (notice the `::type::type` at the end), if I did conditions just like the previous version did, but without defining default type, that would be a compiler error since the `ShortTypeFinder<>::type` would always be seen by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

As long as a byte consists of 8 bits, `sizeof(int16_t)` will always be 2. There are also types requiring at least 16 bits of size and some other interesting types.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer